# Is it possible to restrict switch to use particular cases only in kotlin/JAVA?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

Is it possible to restrict switch for using particular case.

Here is my scenario :

```
class XYZ {
    public static final String DEFAULT = "DEFAULT";
    public static final String BIG_TEXT = "BIG_TEXT";
    public static final String BIG_PICTURE = "BIG_PICTURE";
    public static final String CAROUSEL = "CAROUSEL";
    public static final String GIF = "GIF";

     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({DEFAULT, BIG_TEXT, BIG_PICTURE, CAROUSEL, GIF})
    public @interface NotificationStyle {}

    @NotificationStyle
    public String style() {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(carouselItems)) {
            return CAROUSEL;
        } 
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(gifItems)) {
            return GIF;
        } else {
            return DEFAULT;
        }
    }
}
```

So here I have define one StringDef interface and restricting `style()` just to return `@NotificationStyle` specified values and here is my switch case

```
// Some other class

XYZ obj = new XYZ()

switch (obj.style()) {
    case XYZ.BIG_PICTURE:
    //Something something
    break;
    case XYZ.BIG_PICTURE:
    //Something something
    break;
    case "Not available to execute":
    //Something something
    break;
    default : //Something something
}
```

I know `obj.style()` will only return restricted values but I want to somehow restrict switch case to even provide this case here

```
case "Not available to execute":
    //Something something
    break;
```

As this will be unreachable code always.

*Please do not look for the code and syntax , just looking for concept here.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you wanna write a dead code? If you know something is not going to happen for sure, you can ignore that case rather than spending time maintaining dead codes..

Comment: @SamuelRobert As I mentioned I am just looking for concept if possible , as we work with 30 - 40 people of team so it might happen. Why to use or not is different question all together. And i am very curious person in nature :)

Comment: I understand.. Consider this example, `if ((1 + 1) != 2) {//Bizzare}`, Now tell me do you wanna write that condition in your code? If you do, May be you should learn to trust your compiler and programming language that you are working on, Remember, If you don't have a problem, you don't need a solution.. BTW the non-problem is already taken care by the compiler in terms of `RunTimeExceptions` catch that... Although If I were to review your code, I wouldn't let this go to production ;-)

Comment: You could use enum in Java, and sealed class in Kotlin (or enum class as well)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a switch over a `String`, right? That's why you can, of course, add cases, that won't really happen (like `"Not available to execute"`). Why don't you just change your possible Strings to an `enum` and make `obj.style` return a constant from that enum? This is how you can restict those `Strings`.

```
fun style(): XYZValues {
    if (true) {
        return XYZValues.BIG_TEXT
    }
    return XYZValues.DEFAULT
}

enum class XYZValues(desc: String) {
    DEFAULT("DEFAULT"),
    BIG_TEXT("BIG_TEXT")
    //more }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    when (style()) {
        XYZValues.BIG_TEXT -> println("1")
        XYZValues.DEFAULT -> println("2")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `style()` method almost acts like an `Enum`

Comment: I understand that he wants to restrict the cases inside style, so nobody can add nonsense cases

Comment: Thanks @s1m0nw1 Don't want to use enum as well, as not good to use in android.

Comment: As it increases app size. So I prefer to avoid it.